# How to make this code for only check 200 Header response and fast working?

Tags: python, security

I found this python code for check vulnerability of website. It works fine but i need some modifications. This script grab all HTTP response (probably 200, 301, 302 and others but not 404). But now i want to only grab which is 200 OK response, not 301 or others. How can I make this. Also this script run slow. Is there any way to speed up this script for thread in python?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Follow Me For More If You Like It Give It A Star
import requests 
def FindAll():
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    f=open('list.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')
    o=open('fixed.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')
    with open('result.txt', 'w') as result:
        for line in f:
            if line == "":
                continue;
            newline=line.split('/')
            parent_url=newline[2]
            for line in o:
                if line == "":
                    continue;
                final_url='http://' + parent_url + '/' + line 
                try:
                    r = requests.get(final_url,headers=headers,timeout=3)
                    r.raise_for_status()
                except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
                    continue;
                except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                    continue;
                except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
                    continue;
                else:
                    print('\033[92m' + 'Found->' + final_url) 
                    result.write(final_url+"\n")
print('\033[94m'+'Just Started The Panel_FInder. Please Wait')

FindAll()
print("Program Finished, See The result.txt File For Ur Result")
```

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Comment: The response code will be in `r.status_code` (an int).

Comment: that's 2 different questions. please ask separate questions

Comment: @alani not getting luck to add this on 

"""     r = requests.get(final_url,headers=headers,timeout=3)
     r.status_code()
     r.raise_for_status()
"""

Comment: All I'm saying is that `r.status_code` is what the property is called; how you use it is up to you, but it's not a getter function that you call to obtain the status code, it is a property that you can use directly (so get rid of the `()`).

Answer (score 0):

The response code will be displayed once you print the status code. You can filter it out them by having an if statement to filter out the other status codes.

Regarding speed, you should multi thread the function. In your function's parameter have a variable called num or something and set it to zero. Everytime the request is done, increase zero by one. Then mutlithread the function. If you run 5 threads, it will run 5x times as faster. When you have the num variable, it will prevent any url skipping, etc.

Comment: If you can please write some code for grabbing the 200 OK status on my final result file.